# Getting Authentication failure message in Onedrive login

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, onedrive

I am getting Authentication Failure message to login to OneDrive.
Here Is My Code:

```
public async static void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var scopes = new[] {
              "onedrive.readwrite",
              "onedrive.appfolder",
              "wl.signin"
        };

            _client = Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.OneDriveClient.GetMicrosoftAccountClient("d5f4ce5f-116a-4b77-a5a7-bd81802cdc7e","urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", scopes, null, null, null);
            OnedriveClient._client = _client;
            var session = await _client.AuthenticateAsync();
           // AppSettings.SkyDriveLogin = true;

            var AccessToken = _client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
            //REST API to request info about the signed-in user
            var uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={AccessToken}");
```

Here is My Error:

[image]

How can I solve this?